# AngularJS: Pass an object into a state using $state.go()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to pass an object with `$state.go()` to another state , but the `$stateParams` is not getting populated .
I have tried everything I could find on web and stackoverflow , but none worked for me. thanks in advance for your help.

here is the code :

```js
MyApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('productList', {
      views:{
        "main_view":{
          templateUrl: 'pages/productList.html',
          controller: 'productListController'
        },
        "second_view":{}
      }
  });
  
  $stateProvider.state('productDetail', {
      views:{
        "main_view":{
          templateUrl: 'pages/productDetail.html',
          url:'/productDetail',
          params:{
          productObj: null
        },
          controller: 'productDetailController',
        },
        "second_view":{}
      }
  });
  
}
MyApp.controller('productListController',function($state,$scope,$http, $window){
    $http
    .get('api/item/index')
    .then(function (response) {
      $scope.items = response.data;
    });
    $scope.showProductDetails = function(argItem){
        console.log(argItem); // will show the argItem object in logs 
        $state.go('productDetail',{productObj:argItem}); // here is the problem
}
});
MyApp.controller('productDetailController',function($stateParams,$state,$scope){
  console.log($stateParams);   //Empty
  console.log($state.params)   //Empty
});
```

```html
<!-- using AngularJs v1.5.5 and ui-router v0.2.18 -->

<!-- this is  pages/productList.html  templateUrl page-->
<article  ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div  class="thumbnail">
    <a ng-click="showProductDetails(item)"  class="btn btn-info">{{item.name}}</a>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: try url:'/productDetail/:productObj' in productDetail state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `params : {}` does **not** belong to `view`, but to **`state`**:

```
$stateProvider.state('productDetail', {
  // this, state level, is a right place for params 
  params:{
      productObj: null
  },
  views:{
    "main_view":{
      templateUrl: 'pages/productDetail.html',
      url:'/productDetail',
      // this is wrong place
      // params:{
      //  productObj: null
      // },
      controller: 'productDetailController',
    },
    "second_view":{}
  }
});
```